# Insert all dates between two dates into Mysql Database with opposite data

Tags: php, loops, insert

I'm trying to insert rows into a DB between 2 dates.

Here is my table

[image]

A user will complete a short form stating start and end dates and the values for the first week (0 or 1)

```
$Start=$_GET['Start'];
$End=$_GET['End'];
$WorkDays=$_GET['WorkDays'];
```

`$WorkDays` is either 0 or 1 (0 is mon,tue,wed and 1 is thu,fri,sat)

I can insert the first week fine using the below:

```
$mon=$Start;              
$tue=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Start. ' + 1 days'));
$wed=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Start. ' + 2 days'));
$thu=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Start. ' + 3 days'));
$fri=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Start. ' + 4 days'));
$sat=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Start. ' + 5 days'));

if($WorkDays==1){$monWork=1; $tueWork=1; $wedWork=1; $thuWork=0; $friWork=0; $satWork=0; }
if($WorkDays==2){$monWork=0; $tueWork=0; $wedWork=0; $thuWork=1; $friWork=1; $satWork=1; }
```

Then I have insert queries for each day mon-sat.

I then need the same script to look at all dates between the start and end and insert into the same db, but each day must have the oposite value of the last weeks day.

**E.G**

Week 1: mon=1, tue=1, wed=1, thu=0, fri=0, sat=0
Week 2: mon=0, tue=0, wed=0, thu=1, fri=1, sat=1

Here is what I have tried:

```
//Get the date 1 after the start date as first week already inserted
   $SevenDays=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Start. ' + 7 days'));  
    $startTime = strtotime( $SevenDays);
    $endTime = strtotime( $End );

//Loop through each day between the start and end date
    for ( $i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i = $i + 86400 ) { 
    $given_date =  date( 'Y-m-d', $i );
    $given_date_day =  date( 'l', $i );

//Select the same day the week before
    $result1512=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RosteredPatternHours where PatternID='$PatternID' and WorkingDate='$SevenDaysGiven'")or die('Error 84' . mysql_error());
        for ($ii = 1; $ii <= mysql_num_rows($result1512); $ii++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result1512);  
        $Day = $row ['Day'];
        $Working = $row ['Working'];

//Set Working to opposite of last week
        if($Working==1){$WorkingDay=0;}
        if($Working==0){$WorkingDay=1;}
```

Then i add my insert query.

This only seems to add one week and not all days between start and end